# Conditional inline CSS for different browser chrome & firefox

Tags: css

I have written a css for div positioning. 
here is the css

```
background-color: white; 
border-style: outset; 
margin: 115px 0px 0px -40px;
```

When I see the output in firefox then div position is ok but when I see this in chrome then output gets distorted due to `margin: 145px 0px 0px -40px;`

for chrome margin should be `margin: 115px 0px 0px -40px;`

So I search google and found a snippet and I applied but did not work. which was

```
style="width:310;height:402;background-color:white;border-style:outset; if webkit (margin:115px 0 0 -40px) else  (margin:146px 0 0 -40px);"
```

So guide me how could I write conditional inline css for chrome...any idea. Thanks

Comment: Are you using a css reset to begin with? Firefox and chrome should be the same when it comes to rendering.

Comment: Where did you get the snippet? Conditional CSS, requires a bit more than just adding the IF..etc...

Comment: i search google and found the snippet.

Comment: how to define margin-top:100px;
margin-bottom:100px;
margin-right:50px;
margin-left:50px; for chrome

Comment: there are no `if else` conditions in css... wherever you found the snippet - this is wrong. Post some more of your markup, i find it very strange, that Chrome and FF differ that much. Probably there is a problem in your html.

Comment: Conditional inline CSS is going to require JavaScript(or client side processing) to process the inline markup, you need to check the documentation where you found the snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a test page, did not find what you said this situation.
maybe you write a test page.
Strictly speaking, firefox chrome is the standard of modern browers, should not have this kind of situation has.

```
*{ margin:0; padding:0;}
body{font:12px/1.5 arial;background:#fff;}
.test{background-color: white; border-style: outset; margin: 115px 0px 0px -40px;}

<div class="test"></div>
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/VuTWc/)